# User environment state report

Tags: windows, computing-environment

What is the most easy way to help a user create a report about his environment?

Conditions:

1. Do not need administrator permissions
2. Run locally on user's PC
3. The result should be placed in a file
4. Need to verify is there a specific file, software or other information available without administrator permissions

**UPDATE**: I need the easiest way. In my opinion it should be a user-friendly utility, maybe a wizard, which should run and verify the user environment state.

Comment: What do you want in this report ?

Comment: @Ofiris I need to verify does specific files exist, at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

Use registry keys available to the user. Configuration Files. Almost all information is available to read and to receive it is not prohibited. The biggest problem is that you probably can not read the security log of a user without administrative rights. All other magazines are available for reading. That is, diagnosis, a list of the software, except logs security events will be available. Further, the prevailing majority of people working in the Windows Family systems under the Provo administrator. And if you added a manifesto of its executable file, then the interaction with the protection UAC will only happen once. Moreover simple queries like:

test user account local administrator workstation:

```
wmic NETLOGIN  Where (Caption="%username%" AND Privileges=2) get Caption, Name, FullName, NumberOfLogons, PrimaryGroupId, Workstations, BadPasswordCount, LogonServer
```

test user account Active Directory administrator domain:

```
dsquery * -filter "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(name=%username%)(adminCount=1))" -attr name mail sn givenName userAccountControl
```

help you determine the level of user rights.

Use `wmic` or WSH (vbscript).

example: [Batch file which takes care of finding all unprotected accounts and feeds that to vbscript](http://blogs.dirteam.com/blogs/kapes/default.aspx)

way 2, need run "Help and Support" service:

```
SET msinfo32="%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\MSInfo\msinfo32.exe"
REM xml report:
msinfo32 /computer w17 /nfo w17.nfo /categories +all 
REM nfo(ini) report:
msinfo32 /computer w17 /report w17.txt /categories +all
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But I need the easiest way... In my opinion it can be utility with user-friendly GUI, maybe wizard, which should run and verify user environment state. Do you have any idea what I can use?

Comment: @Sasha See way 2, on GUI `msinfo32` or use in command-line.

Comment: Thank you. But in your second approach I need to enter specific computer name for each user machine. It will be a big problem for a lot of PC. Maybe there is a way to run this remotely..

Comment: How can I solve the question #4 using your approach?

Comment: @Sasha Skip /computer param. Paragraph 4, depends on the security settings.

Comment: Sorry, for the lack of understanding, but can you provide example how to check is there file "C:\temp\test.exe." on the target machine? Please.

Comment: @Sasha `IF EXIST %windir%\win.ini type %windir%\win.ini` I think you first need to create a detailed specification requirements. Then maybe you can get what you need for the money).

Comment: Thanks. But with all respect, this approach does not look like user-friendly and may be used only by administrator with good skills...